# XBRL output generation need clarifications

Tags: file, xbrl

I have a task assigned to generate XBRL file. I'm confused with lot of things while exploring XBRL.

I want to know what are the inputs needed for generating XBRL output. please describe all the possibilities.

Please help me, whole over the internet i'm searching for months but cannot correlate how everything is going.

There are COREP and FINREP these are reporting formats i think. If i have to generate COREP based XBRL what are the inputs and what will be output ?

If user data provided in few excel sheets, where will i get taxonomies, how it can be transformed ?

Comment: Thank you Charles Mager, actually i have to automate this xbrl generation process by using SAP BODS. Is there any answers for to generate xbrl without buying other tools ?.

Answer (score 1):

The EBA COREP/FINREP taxonomies are about as complicated as XBRL gets.  You can download the taxonomies and supporting documentation [from their website](http://www.eba.europa.eu/regulation-and-policy/supervisory-reporting/implementing-technical-standard-on-supervisory-reporting-data-point-model-).  These taxonomies are updated twice a year (though the next release is delayed).

The taxonomies make use of (and therefore require you to have understanding of) [XBRL 2.1](http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html), [Dimensions 1.0](http://www.xbrl.org/specification/dimensions/rec-2012-01-25/dimensions-rec-2006-09-18+corrected-errata-2012-01-25-clean.html), [Table Linkbase](http://www.xbrl.org/specification/table-linkbase/REC-2014-03-18/table-linkbase-REC-2014-03-18.html) (they still use a PWD version) and [Formula 1.0](http://www.xbrl.org/specification/formula/rec-2009-06-22/formula-rec-2009-06-22.html).  The level of understanding you would require depends on whether you use an existing XBRL processor or attempt this yourself.  I'm not aware of any open source XBRL solution that's up to the task (most don't support Table or Formula and nearly all are poorly documented).

In terms of transformation, it's not straightforward.  The EBA link above will lead you to some Excel templates.  You then need to find some way of matching cells in this to the concepts and dimensions in the taxonomy. This already complex and unreliable process would be complicated by tables with open Y and Z axes.  There may be some 'short cut' by using the Access DPM database (from which the taxonomy is generated).

There are then various [filing rules](http://www.eba.europa.eu/documents/10180/502670/EBA+XBRL+Filing+Rules+for+v2.0.0.pdf) for submission to EBA.  Submission is via a country's NCA which then may apply its own specifc rules or may even extend and modify the taxonomies.

EBA also has a list of around 2,000 validations (implemented in Formula 1.0 and summarised [in an Excel file](http://www.eba.europa.eu/documents/10180/997051/EBA+Validation+Rules+-+2015+02+27.xlsx/e2f67f7d-1bea-43c6-a295-fc2f1bd894b9)) that the filing is required to pass else it will be rejected.  As some of these have turned out to be erroneous, EBA tends to publish a list every few months activating or de-activating certain rules on this list.  Validations are also added and removed in each release of the taxonomies.

This is not something you'd take on lightly.  If you are working for a financial institution that's required to make COREP or FINREP submissions I'd strongly suggest you buy some proven reporting solution.

Answer (score 0):

[COREP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Banking_Authority#Common_Reporting_Framework) and FINREP are two standardized reporting specifications edited by the EBA, and so are named the corresponding taxonomies.

You should start by looking some [introduction at the xbrl standard](http://www.ifrs.org/xbrl/resources/Pages/Fundamentals.aspx), and there is also a good [COREP/FINREP description](http://www.eurofiling.info/corepTaxonomy/descriptions/COREP%20-%20FINREP%20Documentation-2007-04-20.pdf).

If you have some excel sheets and want to produce some xbrl instances, you need an xbrl processor to perform the translation. Writing one yourself is a big task. There are some already available in [open-source form](http://www.xbrlwiki.info/index.php?title=Open_Source_and_XBRL) (or [not](http://www.wikixbrl.info/index.php?title=XBRL_Industry_Solutions)).

Comment: Thank you @Seki for the answer, is there any possibility to generate this xbrl document with SAP BODS by taking input from tables and making target as XML file ?

Comment: @alpteja: I don't know. I never used any SAP product (but PowerBuilder, but it was not produced by SAP) and only worked to produce xbrl via a processor made in java from some xml formated data and a data mapping.

Comment: Thank you @Seki. Is there any small tutorial to generate sample xbrl for a taxonomy, to check how this works. You can send to my email if possible alpteja@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Just download de dpm database from the eba.
start from 
TaxonomyTableVersion.TaxonomyID,
TableVersion,
Tablecell,
CellPosition,
AxisOrdinate,AxisOrdinetCategorie

Datapointversion
      Members Metric

Which results in

```
        <!--001.010.050    Grey :Not UnusedAxis : Not eba_AT:mi96    APR=eba_AP:x42,BAS=eba_BA:x9,CRM=eba_CP:x22,MCY=eba_MC:x195,PRP=eba_PL:x10,TRI=eba_TR:x4 -->
        <xbrli:context id="C_07.00.a.001.010.050">
            <xbrli:entity>
                <xbrli:identifier scheme="http://www.swift.com">0400040965</xbrli:identifier>
            </xbrli:entity>
            <xbrli:period>
                <xbrli:instant>2017-06-30</xbrli:instant>
            </xbrli:period>
            <xbrli:scenario>
                <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="eba-dim:APR">eba-AP:x42</xbrldi:explicitMember>
                <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="eba-dim:BAS">eba-BA:x9</xbrldi:explicitMember>
                <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="eba-dim:CRM">eba-CP:x22</xbrldi:explicitMember>
                <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="eba-dim:MCY">eba-MC:x195</xbrldi:explicitMember>
                <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="eba-dim:PRP">eba-PL:x10</xbrldi:explicitMember>
                <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="eba-dim:TRI">eba-TR:x4</xbrldi:explicitMember>
            </xbrli:scenario>
        </xbrli:context>
        <eba-met:mi96 contextRef="C_07.00.a.001.010.050" decimals="-3" unitRef="U-EUR">0</eba-met:mi96>
```